# ObjC - method works on application launch, but not button press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a class called `MyView` with a method `-(void)drawBoxes:(NSColor*)aColor` that draws twenty small squares of a certain color in random locations within the view.

My app delegate contains a member `MyView* myView`.

Here's my app delegate's `.m` file:

```
@implementation RSTAppDelegate

@synthesize myView;
@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Application launched!");
    [self.myView drawBoxes:[NSColor greenColor]];
}

-(IBAction)buttonFunction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");
    [self.myView drawBoxes:[NSColor redColor]];

}

@end
```

And here's the `drawBoxes` function in `MyView`:

```
-(void)drawBoxes:(NSColor*)aColor
{
    for (int n=0;n<20;n++)
    {
        NSRect xRect = NSMakeRect(rand()%100,rand()%100,10, 10);
        [aColor set];
        NSRectFill(xRect);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I connected a button to the `buttonFunction` method. I run the program and the `drawBoxes` method from the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method gets called no problem, and 20 green squares appear.

However, when I click my button, no red boxes are drawn. The console confirms that the button was pressed and is hooked up correctly, but for some reason, `drawBoxes` isn't drawing my boxes.

Thoughts?

Comment: NSLog under xRect and log origin of boxes and see if boxes overlaping?

Comment: no, even changing the button code to trigger a different function that draws a single rectangle in a different position doesn't work.

Comment: Have you made sure that pressing the button actually reaches your code?

Comment: You cannot draw anything to the screen outside of a `drawRect:` method. You can, however, set ivars that `drawRect:` uses to draw the view.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I don't think this is a true duplicate. I came across that question, but the author has his button trigger method within the App Delegate class as opposed to within a specific view. In the accepted answer, the lack of contexts are mentioned as the issue. But I thought that would be taken care of by keeping my methods explicitly within the `MyView` class. Is this incorrect? Do I still need to specify a `NSGraphicsContext` to draw within?

Comment: @RyanTuck Read the answer in the duplicate more carefully.

Comment: @matt - boom. Although the accepted answer isn't really an "answer" at all, the upvoted answer below it lead me to a solution. The lock/unlock focus trick worked, although the answer author suggests this isn't a good model to pursue down the line. I'm gathering that `NSRectFill` shouldn't really be used outside of `drawRect` methods at all in a proper OO code environment, since any given drawn shape should be an object itself.